# How to display image from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

How to display an image using JavaScript from an array creating in JavaScript.

Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Display it where? Do you have an HTML page, maybe? They make these sort of things much easier.

Comment: Yes, i have a html page. sry forgot to mention that but the value is stored in an object array.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got an image tag in your HTML layout, with a given `id`, you can control its content with javascript:

```
function updateFullImage(id, url) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    img.src = url ;
}
```

and the browser (FF at leat) will automatically reload your image

Answer (score 1):

You can create an image in JavaScript: `var img = new Image(); img.src = "path-to-image";` and then add it to the DOM (depending on if you're using a js library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) or not this will vary in complexity). Can you be more specific as to your circumstances?